# What is the entry point of this basic MFC Dialogue Box Application?

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++, mfc, entry-point

Starting out with GUI programming with C++. So, following some tutorials, I 'wrote' the following code to display a dialogue box. To be honest, the Visual Studio 2015 Wizard did most of the job, but here is the code file. It correctly displays the dialogue box pointed by the identifier, but I really cannot figure out how it works. To begin with, what is the entry point, of the code? There is not even a function, so what exactly executes when I build and run it?

```
#include<afxwin.h>
#include"resource.h"

class CExampleDlg :public CDialog
{
public:
    CExampleDlg():CDialog(IDD_EXAMPLE_DLG){}
    ~CExampleDlg(){}
};

class CExample:public CWinApp
{public:
    BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CExampleDlg myDlg;
        m_pMainWnd = &myDlg;
        myDlg.DoModal();
        return TRUE;

    }
};
CExample MyApp;
```

Comment: CWinApp: _"An application object provides member functions for initializing your application (and each instance of it) __and for running the application__."_ see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362kaah4.aspx  When created it calls the `InitInstance` member function which you have overridden.  As `MyApp` is a global all this runs before the usual entry point of `WinMain` (or `main` for console applications).

Comment: MFC is really dead. I suggest dropping it and using another library/framework like Qt.

Comment: @AndreiAndrey SO discourages opinions with no facts to back them up - please substantiate your post.

Comment: @AndreiAndrey: MFC is anything but dead. It's being used in way more applications on a single platform, than Qt with all supported platforms combined.

Comment: `CExample MyApp;` instantiates a `CExample` instance, its c'tor is the user-provided entry point in an MFC application.

Comment: The entrypoint for a GUI app is WinMain().  You'll link one that's provided by the MFC libraries, it knows how to use CWinApp.  You have the source code on your machine, look at vc/atlmfc/src/mfc/appmodul.cpp and winmain.cpp

Comment: You write: _There is not even a function_: what do you think `InitInstance()` is? The entrypoint _you_  need to deal with is `CExample::InitInstance()`.

Comment: you should change the return true to false, because when the dialog returns the app is finishing. For SDI and MDI you need to return true. Dialog app is special case because you wait on the doModal.

Comment: this is your entry point: [CDialog::OnInitDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwz35s59(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @IInspectable: source of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798930/what-is-the-entry-point-of-this-basic-mfc-dialogue-box-application#comment76578145_44798930 please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike normal c/c++ application where the entry point is main and you have full control over the flow of execution. MFC applications are event driven. The code you write is executed based on the events that occur due to user interaction with the application like, clicking on the button, entering text in the text box etc. When there is no interaction the application sits idle.

1) The best place to is OnInitDialog to place your initialization code. You can initialize all the member variables in OnInitDialog. (Remember winMain is the entry point for windows application. But in MFC this is embedded deep down in the boilerplate code.)

2) Add message handlers to handle the user actions to execute your core logic later. For e.g.: If you have a button on the dialog then you need to add the message handler function for the button which will get invoked when the user clicks on that button. This can be done easily using the class wizard  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748520.aspx).